# How can I get notified when a question in my domain is asked?

Tags: discussion, questions

As I don't want to check the questions all the time is there anyway to get notified via email that a question in Java or Android has been asked?

Comment: Do you want to get 2000 mails a day? Because that's a conservative estimate of the amount of Java and Android questions SO gets every day. Also, there's no guarantee that a question falls into your domain just because it's tagged with either; both are rather broad topics. Just favourite some tags and use tag searches to find interesting questions to answer.

Comment: The tag pages get updated instantly for new questions. No need to reload the main page all the time. Try it out

Comment: If you hover over a tag, there's a subscribe link.

Comment: **[This](http://cdn.stripersonline.com/4/40/200x200px-ZC-4056fafa_girl-getting-hit-in-the-face-with-hotdogs-gif.gif)** will be your inbox. Might as well get emailed about new PHP questions while your at it.