# Any way to get notified when a question is asked based on my favourite tags

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I know there's a similar question, *[How can I get notified when a question in my domain is asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285229/how-can-i-get-notified-when-a-question-in-my-domain-is-asked)*. But it's not answered very well.

My question is, to get notified if a question is asked based on my combination of tags. Like I want to answer question based on `android` and `firebase`. So if I get a desktop notification, "NOT EMAIL" so I can answer the question. Also, I will be able to turn off notifications if I don't want to get notified any more. In this way when I am in mood to answer questions I can just turn on notification for some tags I like.

If there are any ways for that let me know. Else consider this in your update, because it will be a huge help, since I don't have to check question every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a tag's RSS feed.

For example, for JavaScript:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=javascript&sort=newest

Combine that with an RSS reader that can show you desktop notifications, and you're all set!

Comment: I used rss feeder https://www.feednotifier.com and rss feed https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=android%20firebase&sort=newest - Because i want questions having both tags. and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

I know you said, NOT EMAIL. I'll mention the current email notifications only to note that we are looking at making improvements to better integrate this feature on Stack Overflow directly and possibly allow you to choose desktop browser notifications versus email. Please let us know if you think this would be valuable.

To see how this feature works today go to https://stackexchange.com/filters/ and click on "New filter" and set up the criteria. Make sure you specify if you want to just see updates from a specific site (such as Stack Overflow). You can receive updates as frequently as every 15 minutes which can be quite overwhelming on some popular tags. So beware.

[image]

Comment: i like it. But the problem is i want to get notified by the questions which has both android and firebase tags. I want combination of tags. In that way i can even filter more and i will only get questions based on my expertise.

Comment: Anything that doesn't allow a complex combination of tags (a boolean expression) is pretty useless.